# Como usar Data binding com layouts distintos no Android?

Tags: android, layout-responsivo, android-databinding

Estou fazendo um `app` Android que apresenta uma lista de endereços e um mapa com estes endereços.

Na vertical, os dois fragmentos aparecem em abas dentro de um `viewPager`.

/res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContainerV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myContainerV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpagerV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXX" />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

e na horizontal, são dois painéis que aparecem lado a lado:

/res/layout-land/activity_main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContainerH"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myContainerH"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/runPanel"
            android:name="br.com.cadima.motonoix.fragments.ListFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recycler" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/markersMapPanel"
            android:name="br.com.cadima.motonoix.fragments.MarkersFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXX" />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Estou tentando usar databinding e para isso, no `onCreate` da `MainActivity`, a variavel de binding é gerada:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
               // se o layout estiver na horizontal...


    } else {
            // se estiver na vertical, ajusta o `viewPager`
        setupViewPager(activityMainBinding.viewpagerV);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

}
```

O problema é que quando os dois layouts estão presentes no projeto, apenas o da pasta `/layout-land` é acessível pelo `activityMainBinding`. e estas ultimas linhas dão erro porque o simbolo não pode ser resolvido.

```
    } else {
            // se estiver na vertical, ajusta o `viewPager`
        setupViewPager(activityMainBinding.viewpagerV);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

Quando deleto o layout na horizontal, as views do layout vertical ficam acessíveis.

Como se faz para usar o databinding com layouts distintos?

ATUALIZAÇÃO: O `app` já está funcionando. Quero melhorar a performance e por isso, resolvi adotar o data binding.

Já pesquisei antes de perguntar e vi alguns quebra galhos, como usar um único layout.xml e desativar as views pelo código, mas eu tenho diversos layouts de acordo com orientação e idioma... Imagina o pesadelo de ter de manter isso tudo pelo código.

Este layout não tem um data model associado, mas os fragmentos que ele vai mostrar terão. E como o app tem vários idiomas e layouts diferentes para tamanho de tela, uma forma fácil de realizar o data binding é essencial.

Talvez seja melhor partir para uma alternativa como butter knife.

O mais importante é melhorar a performance e como o data binding atravessa a UI uma vez só, dá um ganho interessante.

Comment: Qual a versão do Gradle que está a usar?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente, os erros eram mesmo do Android Studio. A solução para que o IDE conseguisse 'enxergar' as views de ambos layouts (padrão e land) foi feita em três passos:

1)

```
File > Invalidate Cache / restart...
```

2)

```
Build > Clean Project
```

3)

```
Build > Rebuild Project
```

O `APP` ainda não está como queria, mas a razão que motivou a pergunta foi solucionada desta forma.